# Rocky Linux 8.6 Rstudio Server Open Source 2022.07.2 PAM acct_mgmt failure

Tags: r, rstudio-server, centos8, pam

I was wondering if anyone has found a solution to this problem.

### Rocky Linux 8.6 Rstudio Server Open Source 2022.07.2 PAM acct_mgmt failure

Pamtester output:

```
[user@super_cool_server downloads]$ pamtester -v rstudio aaron.oster authenticate acct_mgmt open_session close_session
pamtester: invoking pam_start(rstudio, aaron.oster, ...)
pamtester: performing operation - authenticate
Password:
pamtester: successfully authenticated
pamtester: performing operation - acct_mgmt
pamtester: Permission denied
[user@super_cool_server downloads]$ pamtester -v rstudio aaron.oster authenticate open_session close_session
pamtester: invoking pam_start(rstudio, aaron.oster, ...)
pamtester: performing operation - authenticate
Password:
pamtester: successfully authenticated
pamtester: performing operation - open_session
pamtester: sucessfully opened a session
pamtester: performing operation - close_session
pamtester: session has successfully been closed.
```

### General Info

We have Centos 7 machines with working versions of rstudio server 1.2 and no login issues. Tried to use this RS open source 1.2 on rocky as a control but it fails to run.

### My attempts to resolve

1. No file etc/pam.d/common-account exist as described here: https://docs.rstudio.com/rsp/configuration/authentication/active-directory/

Comment: Solved By Rstudio Team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Rstudio Team on community form. Please see link below.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/rocky-linux-8-6-rstudio-server-open-source-2022-07-2-pam-acct-mgmt-failure/149204/4